# What pitch should my guitar be in

Tags: acoustic-guitar, pitch, tuner

I just started playing guitar and I got I tuner to tune my guitar as I don't know how to do it by ear. I had to choose a pitch but I wasn't sure which one so I'm a bit confused. Can somebody please help.

Comment: It would be helpful to know the specific make and model of tuner, and what you mean by "choose a pitch" (i.e. what control on the device are you talking about) for that device in order to provide a good answer.

Comment: I interpret this as "how to I properly use my tuner" and not generic "how to tune" -- thus not dupe; but this really needs additional info from the OP.

Comment: Daisy, welcome to the site!  Please clarify as per Dave's comments if the duplicate question does not help.

Answer (score 1):

The standard tuning, which is the most likely tuning your came in would be this

```
E for the top string (thickest string), 82.41 Hz
A for the next string down, 110.00 Hz
D for the next string down after A, 146.83 Hz
G, 196.00 Hz
B, 246.94 Hz
E for the bottom string (thinnest string),  329.63 Hz
```

Answer (score -1):

E A D G B E

or

D A D G B D

or

D G D G B D

as some possible answers